# isAny way to import of all variables to packages in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hello There my problem simple but i cant find any way to fix this some times when we import just file thats be enough.

like

```js
import './reset.css'
import './App.css';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import 'web-vitals'
```

when i import like that there package codes are coming to my ide.

so i want to import chakra-ui **all** variables because some times.

```
import { Alert ,
  Image,
  Button,
  Text,
  Box, 
  Modal,
    ModalOverlay,
    ModalContent,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalBody,
    ModalCloseButton,
    useDisclosure,
    FormLabel,
    FormControl,
    Input,
    Textarea} from '@chakra-ui/react'
```

can be like that i want to inject to all variables to my ide(how) i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is following:

```
import * as chakra from '@chakra-ui/react';

// Then use it like this

const a = new chakra.Image()
```